# Allow only signed in users to see external html site hosted on the same server and domain (in sub folder)

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a PHP site (**site A**, CakePHP 2.3) with its own login system. Then I have another "site" (it's actually an html generated ebook with its own index.html) in the same server, but on a different folder, let's call it **site B**.

I'm trying to allow **only users that have a valid session on site A** (have logged in with valid credentials) to view that ebook (access that index.html file). The main idea behind this is to prevent users from directly sharing site B's URL.

This would be easy if I could check the user's session on Site A from Site B, I could just check the $_SESSION variable, but that's not possible.

What's the simplest way to accomplish this? While not preferably, it's okay if I have to edit that index.html file from site B to add any code that could help with this.

One way I thought about was to do some **javascript redirect** from site A to site B that includes a **POST variable**, if the variable doesn't exist, then nothing is shown. This would require adding some php on that index.html on site B but I'm not sure it's the best solution, I wonder if there's something better.

Also, I have 100s of these ebooks so if it's something I can apply massively it would be much better.

**EDIT:**

For clarification, both sites are in the same server and have same "domain". To open site B I use a symlink from site A. For example:

- Site A URL: http://example.com
- Site B URL: PHP Redirect from site A to '/symlink/to/siteB/location/') which in practicality takes user to http://example.com/symlink/to/siteB/location/

Comment: Are "site A" and "site B" actually different domains?

Comment: @PatrickQ same domain, I actually use a symlink from site A to open the location of site B in the server, in case that matters.

Comment: @PatrickQ edited the question to clarify that point

Comment: I'd hide the ebook-html files in a non-public folder and serve them via _one_ php script, that checks the login.

Comment: If siteB is all html then you have no way of writing code in an html file

Comment: @Jeff sounds like I wanted to do, could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @RiggsFolly correct, I could make that html to index.php, that wouldn't be a problem if necessary

Comment: If they are the same domain, then why are you saying that you can't use sessions?

Comment: The one php script would simply check login (Session), take a param which html file shall be used (an id?) and then include that (from the hidden folder)

Comment: @PatrickQ when I check the $_SESSION variable from site B nothing is shown (even after session_start() there as well) ... They use the same domain because I'm using the symlink, but they're located in different folders in the server, maybe that's why?

Comment: Being in different folders would have nothing to do with it.  Most people don't put _all_ of their code in one folder.  You should show the code that you've tried that isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Create a proxy

I would use `.htaccess` to redirect any url pointing to pages in the book to a custom `action` in the CakePHP application.

This `action` checks for credentials and if OK then **reads from disk** the actual requested file and sends it to the browser. Do not redirect back or you will cause a redirect loop!

Of course you need to create a redirect that passes the original requested page as a parameter so you know what file to read.

Granted this is not supper efficient but it works. I had to solve the exact same issue in an old project.

#### Notes

Make sure your .htaccess rules only intercept/redirect HTML links or else you need to pay attention to setting up proper response headers for CSS or Image files.

#### Example of .htaccess

This needs to be in the ROOT folder of the book

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^(.*html)$    http://[FULL_LINK_TO_CAKE_APP]/proxy/load/$1
</IfModule>
```

#### Example of the proxy controller

```
namespace App\Controller;

/**
 * Static content controller
 *
 * This controller will render a html file 
 *
 */
class ProxyController extends AppController
{

    public function load($file=null){
        if( !$file ){
            return $this->response->body( "Error: no file specified" );
        }

        //THIS NEEDS TO RESOLVE THE FULL DISK PATH OF YOUR PROTECTED FILES
        $pathToFiles = WWW_ROOT . '/subfolder/';

        if( file_exists( $pathToFiles . $file )){
            $this->response->body( file_get_contents( $pathToFiles.$file) );
            return $this->response;
        }

        $this->response->body('Could not load the file: ' . $pathToFiles . $file);
        return $this->response;
    }
}
```

#### Security

Of course I assume you have setup the `Auth` component correctly in your `AppController` so the controller above will only execute if the user is logged in!

Comment: @IIie Pandia: so the htaccess file would be in the root of site B, correct? How would that redirect rule look like?. Could you provide some sort of example with how the action you mention would look like?

Comment: Added a minimal working example that you will need to adapt to your needs.